# Bound data binding does not work with list items

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list, aura, aura-attribute, databinding

Let me start by showing you what I am doing.

**ParentAppWithListAttr.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute type="List" name="justAList" default="['hello','world']"/>

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.justAList}" action="{!c.justLog}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.justAList}" var="item">
        <p>{!item}</p>
    </aura:iteration>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.justAList}" var="item">
        <c:ChildForEachElementInList justAnItem="{!item}"></c:ChildForEachElementInList>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:application>
```

**ParentAppWithListAttrController.js**

```
({
    justLog : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("old value: " + event.getParam("oldValue"));
        console.log("current value: " + event.getParam("value"));
    }
})
```

**ChildForEachElementInList.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="justAnItem"/>
    <p>Item: {!v.justAnItem}</p>

    <lightning:button variant="base" label="Click child" onclick="{!c.changeAttr}"/>

</aura:component>
```

**ChildForEachElementInListController.js**

```
({
    changeAttr : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.justAnItem", "cool");
    }
})
```

Now when I click `Click child` we can notice that the child component attribute gets updated. While the parent attribute does not. And that is the issue.

What am I missing here? Why parent attribute does not get updated and no console output is produced due to the change handler?

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Something similar, I faced, here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221129/why-auraiteration-doesnt-re-render-when-you-add-element-to-parent-components

Comment: I think this is an inherent misuse of the console.log. You should be using a variable/array to store old values if you want to track the state of the component between clicks.

Comment: @crmprogdev, thank you. I do not understand you. Could you, please, elaborate? Because I am using an array in my example: `<aura:attribute type="List" name="justAList" default="['hello','world']"/>`. And also I am not interested in storing or tracking old values. The perseverance of old data in parent component\`s `aura:attribute` is the issue here. The data in parent component is not updated, while I would expect it to be updated.

Comment: Components need to talk with one another using a mechanism. I don't see where you've defined any Aura Events. That could be one issue with things not updating between components. Only problem with that approach is Events are available to all components in Window (& more). Another approach is "bubbling". How they bubble depends on stacking order in the Container and references between each component. Do those references exist? The console.log is not the place to create references as part of a function. You're expecting to "bubble down" instead of "up" without a reference to parent from child.

Comment: @crmprogdev, `aura:attribute` is the mechanism here. According to [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm) `!` denotes a bi-directional data binding, while `#` denotes an absence of data binding. Since I am using `!`, my components talk with one another using the expressions mechanism. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see where your controller has a list of "justAnItem"s that it iterates on. It appears to me that it thinks it's only swapping out one value, but there's no index of a list that's been selected where it should swap out that value.

Comment: @crmprogdev, are talking about `ParentAppWithListAttrController.js` or about `ChildForEachElementInListController.js`? Thank you.

Comment: Actually I'm talking about both. I said in my initial comments that I thought `ParentAppWithListAttrController.js` use of the console.log was a misuse & not appropriate. Its clear that `ChildForEachElementInListController.js` does not make its changes to a list. So, what does it really do? Does it make them to the element or does it direct them to the Event? It seems a bit unclear to me whether a specif list position or element is being referenced at `v.JustAList[i]` in that controller. As written, it could easily be a reference to any string, not one in the list at position `n`.

Comment: It would seem that your `ParentAppWithListAttrController.js` should be using `v.JustAList` and `v.JustAnItem` where `v.JustAnItem` is located in the position in `v.JustAList` where the Event occurred. The old value of v.JustAnItem is irrelevant. You just need to put the new value in the proper location in the list, then set `JustAList`. If you don't set it, the change is not communicated to all the components.

Comment: @crmprogdev, your last comment solves the issue. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I've reposted my comment as an answer so others can benefit from knowing your question was answered and solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that your `ParentAppWithListAttrController.js` should be using `v.JustAList` and `v.JustAnItem` where `v.JustAnItem` is located in the position in `v.JustAList` where the Event occurred. The old value of v.JustAnItem is irrelevant. You just need to put the new value in the proper location in the list, then set `JustAList`. If you don't set it, the change is not communicated to all the components.